# Two-point correlation function with interactions

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, correlation-functions

I am reading [Peskin & Schroeder](https://books.google.com/books?id=i35LALN0GosC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) page 289. They discuss only very briefly the path integral for the $\phi^4$ theory. Therefore I am unsure if I understand the main point.

They consider

$$\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}_0-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4$$

with $\mathcal{L}_0=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$.

Now the goal is to calculate:

$$<\Omega| T \phi_H(x_1)\phi_H(x_2)|\Omega>= {\rm lim}_{T\to \infty (1-i\epsilon)}\frac{\int D\phi\, \phi(x_1)\,\phi(x_2)\exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}\right]}{\int D\phi \,\exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}\right]}\tag{9.18}$$

For this they first expand the exponential in the small parameter $\lambda$:

$$\exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}\right]=\exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\int_{-T}^Td^4x\phi^4+\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)\right)$$

Then the numerator of (9.18) is:

$$\int D\phi\, \phi(x_1)\,\phi(x_2)\exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]
-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\int D\phi\, \phi(x_1)\,\phi(x_2)\,\exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]\int_{-T}^Td^4x\phi^4$$

Similarly the denominator:

$$\int D\phi\, \exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]
-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\int D\phi\, \,\exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]\int_{-T}^Td^4x\phi^4$$

Then (9.18) is:

$${\rm lim}_{T\to \infty (1-i\epsilon)}\frac{\int D\phi\, \phi(x_1)\,\phi(x_2)\exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]
-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\int D\phi\, \phi(x_1)\,\phi(x_2)\,\exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]\int_{-T}^Td^4x\phi^4}{\int D\phi\, \exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]
-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\int D\phi\, \,\exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]\int_{-T}^Td^4x\phi^4}\\
={\rm lim}_{T\to \infty (1-i\epsilon)}\frac{(I)-(II)}{1-(III)}$$

with

$$(I)=\frac{\int D\phi\, \phi(x_1)\,\phi(x_2)\exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]}{\int D\phi\, \exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]}\\
(II)=\frac{\frac{\lambda}{4!}\int D\phi\, \phi(x_1)\,\phi(x_2)\,\exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]\int_{-T}^Td^4x\phi^4}{\int D\phi\, \exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]}\\
(III)=\frac{\frac{\lambda}{4!}\int D\phi\, \,\exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]\int_{-T}^Td^4x\phi^4}{\int D\phi\, \exp\left[i\int_{-T}^T d^4x \mathcal{L}_0\right]}$$

Now the goal is to calculate all three terms that appear in the last expression. Is this correct, or is what I am doing too complicated?

Term $(I)$ already known, since it is just the free field case. I also know how to calculate the rest of the terms, but before I do that I want to know if this is the standard way (and easiest way) how to calculate such things...

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/692405/2451

Comment: I suggest you just persevere with the computation .. (By the way, you can expand the denominator in a geometric series and some cancellations will then become possible.  You might find it useful to first compute the generating function, Z(J)=expW(J), whose derivatives give the two-point function you are computing. And if you want a reference that goes through this in a systematic way you can see Sec. 2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02604. )

Comment: Eq (III) is wrong, it cannot depend on $x_1$ and $x_2$, just remove the product $\phi(x_1) \phi(x_2)$ in the integrand.

Comment: You are right, thanks!